# iPhone managedobject delete crashing

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I try to delete some managedobjects by calling in a for loop

```
[managedObject delete];
```

and at of the loop, I call

```
[managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

At the above line, the app crashes and goes nowhere from there. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Add more info to your question. What do you see in the log when it crashes?

Comment: The app itself does not crash.. the simulator simply hangs

Answer (score 0):

Run in the debugger and make sure you are breaking on `objc_exception_throw`.  If you can't catch the break point or produce a crash log you are not going to find much help here.